# Transition matrix (Markov chain) mean values

Tags: probability, markov-chains, transition-matrix

If I have a *n* $\times$ *n* transition matrix and want to find the expected times passing the point *j* if the starting point is *i* and the amount of steps is *m*.

For example
$$P =\begin{bmatrix}0.5&0.5&0&0&0\\0.5&0&0.5&0&0\\0.5&0&0&0.5&0\\0&0&0.5&0&0.5\\0&0.5&0.5&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

*i* = 1, 
 *j* = 5, 
 *m* = 100

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

The transition probabilities after $k$ steps become $\mathbf{P}^k$. Hence, the $(i, j)$ entry of matrix $\mathbf{N}$ below is the expected number of times the chain is in state $j$, given that the chain started in state $i$.

$$\mathbf{N}=\sum_{k=0}^m{\mathbf{P}^k}$$

- If the matrix $\mathbf{I-P}$ is invertible, then the above sum can be expressed as $(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{P}^{m+1})(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{P})^{-1}$ using the geometric sum formula.
- Otherwise, if $\mathbf{P}$ is diagonalizable
  $$\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{Q}^{-1}$$
  where $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ is a diagnoal matrix with elements $\lambda_i$ that are eigen values of $\mathbf{P}$. The matrix $\mathbf{N}$ is then can be given by
  $$\mathbf{N}=\mathbf{Q}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{Q}^{-1}$$
  where $\mathbf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are given by $$d_i=\begin{cases}m+1,&\lambda_i=1\\\frac{1-\lambda_i^{m+1}}{1-\lambda_i},&\lambda_i\neq1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Actually, the matrix $I-P$ is not invertible so the sum cannot be simplified in this way.

Comment: $\mathbf{P}$ is diagonalizable and the sum can be simplified using the second approach.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Your comment has been addressed in the updated answer. I am not sure if either of downvotes are from you. If yes, It means something should be wrong with the post and I would like to know it.